# Adding a Multi reference in latex

Tags: latex, bibliography

I'm using the {thebibliography}{widest-label} enviroment
and I would like to for the citation to appear like the following output:

**code:**

```
cite{1,2}
```

**output:**

```
[1-2]
```

I tried using a lot of packages but it is giving me errors.

**My Code:**

```
 \documentclass[11pt, reqno]{jmcs-t}% cls. for J. Math. Comput. Sci.

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color}
\usepackage[backref = true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
Multiple Citation cite{1,3}
\begin{thebibliography}{widest-label}

\end{thebibliography}

\bibitem{1} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal, {\bf 19} (Date), page--page.
\bibitem{2} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal., {\bf 19} (Date), page--page.
\bibitem{3} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal. Math., {\bf 19} (Date), page--page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a link where we can get the class from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `cite{1,3}` should be `\cite{1,2,3}`
- the `\bibitems` need to be *inside* the `thebibliography` environment
- you should load `hyperref` after the other packages
- you should replace `widest-label` with the widest label, e.g. a single digit number like `3` in your example.
- two letter font commands like `\bf` should not be used
- as the class internally uses the `natbib` package, you can use the `sort&compress` bib option:

```
\documentclass[11pt, reqno]{jmcs-t}% cls. for J. Math. Comput. Sci.
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xparse}
\biboptions{sort&compress}
\usepackage[backref = true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
Multiple Citation \cite{1,2,3}
\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\bibitem{1} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal, {\bfseries 19} (Date), page--page.
\bibitem{2} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal., {\bfseries 19} (Date), page--page.
\bibitem{3} Author, \textit{Title}, Journal. Math., {\bfseries 19} (Date), page--page.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately,  I did everything you said I'm still getting errors is it ok if I sent you the Journal template?

Comment: @Malak If you share some public link to the template, I could take a look

Comment: https://www.isr-publications.com/jmcs/journal-format